# How to parse all children and grandchildren elements from a current node using xml.etree.ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am extracting all the text in xml document. I want to look for tag say **description** and then search through all the children and grandchildren and there could be even more elements and then extract the text.

Here is my code but it is not able to get text inside the grandchildren tags:

```
for element in root.find('description'):
    print 'parent: ', element.tag, '|', element.attrib
    try:
        data.write(element.text)
        for all_tags in element.findall('./'):
            print 'child: ', all_tags.tag, '|', all_tags.attrib
            if all_tags.text:
                data.write('\n')
                data.write(all_tags.text)
                if all_tags.tail:
                    data.write('\n')
                    data.write(all_tags.tail)
                    data.write('\n')
        data.write('\n')
    except TypeError:
        pass
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        unicodestr = element.text.encode("utf-8")
        data.write(unicodestr)

    data.write('\n')
```

The problem is in the `for all_tags` loop.

sample input:

```
<description>
<p num="p-0003">
Protein kinases are involved in the signal transduction pathways linking growth factors, hormones and other cell regulation molecules to cell growth, survival and metabolism under both normal and pathological conditions. One such protein kinase, protein kinase B (also known as Akt), is a serine/threonine kinase that plays a central role in promoting the proliferation and survival of a wide range of cell types, thereby protecting cells from apoptosis (programmed cell death) (Khwaja,
<i>Nature</i>
33-34 (1990)). Three members of the Akt/PKB subfamily of second-messenger regulated serine/threonine protein kinases have been identified and are termed Akt1/PKBα, Akt2/PKBβ, and Akt3/PKBγ. A number of proteins involved in cell proliferation and survival have been described as substrates of Akt in cells. Two examples of such substrates include glycogen synthase kinase-3 (GSK3) and Forkhead transcription factors (FKs). See Brazil and Hemmings,
<i>Trends in Biochemical Sciences</i>
26, 675-664.
</p>
<p num="p-0004">
A number of protein kinases and phosphatases regulate the activity of Akt; For instance, activation of Akt is mediated by phosphatidylinositol 3-kinase (PI3-K), which initiates the binding of second messenger phospholipids to the pleckstrin homology (PH) binding domain of Akt. The binding anchors Akt to plasma membrane and results in phosphorylation and activation of the enzyme. Amplifications of the catalytic subunit of PI3-K, p110α, or mutations in the PI3-K regulatory subunit, p85α, lead to activation of Akt in several types of human cancer. (Vivanco and Sawyers,
<i>Nature Reviews in Cancer</i>
(2002) 2: 489-501.
</p>
<p num="p-0005">
The tumor suppressor, PTEN, is a critical negative regulator of Akt activation by PI3-K. Myers et al.
</p>
</description>
```

In this input, the text after `<i> Nature </i>`  is missed and replaced by text in the first line. This is I believe due to the `all_tags.tail` is getting text from the parent tag not from the children and grandchildren tags.

Comment: Could you clarify the result part a little bit? Are you getting any errors? Could you provide sample input, and actual and expected outputs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`element.findall('./')` explicitly only finds direct children of a tag. The expression to find all descendants is `.//` (double slash).

A simplified version of your loop against the sample given, then results in:

```
>>> for element in root:
...     print 'parent: ', element.tag, '|', element.attrib
...     print element.text
...     for all_tags in element.findall('.//'):
...         print 'child: ', all_tags.tag, '|', all_tags.attrib
...         if all_tags.text:
...             print all_tags.text, '|', all_tags.tail
... 
parent:  p | {'num': 'p-0003'}

Protein kinases are involved in the signal transduction pathways linking growth factors, hormones and other cell regulation molecules to cell growth, survival and metabolism under both normal and pathological conditions. One such protein kinase, protein kinase B (also known as Akt), is a serine/threonine kinase that plays a central role in promoting the proliferation and survival of a wide range of cell types, thereby protecting cells from apoptosis (programmed cell death) (Khwaja,

child:  i | {}
Nature | 
33-34 (1990)). Three members of the Akt/PKB subfamily of second-messenger regulated serine/threonine protein kinases have been identified and are termed Akt1/PKBα, Akt2/PKBβ, and Akt3/PKBγ. A number of proteins involved in cell proliferation and survival have been described as substrates of Akt in cells. Two examples of such substrates include glycogen synthase kinase-3 (GSK3) and Forkhead transcription factors (FKs). See Brazil and Hemmings,

child:  i | {}
Trends in Biochemical Sciences | 
26, 675-664.

parent:  p | {'num': 'p-0004'}

A number of protein kinases and phosphatases regulate the activity of Akt; For instance, activation of Akt is mediated by phosphatidylinositol 3-kinase (PI3-K), which initiates the binding of second messenger phospholipids to the pleckstrin homology (PH) binding domain of Akt. The binding anchors Akt to plasma membrane and results in phosphorylation and activation of the enzyme. Amplifications of the catalytic subunit of PI3-K, p110α, or mutations in the PI3-K regulatory subunit, p85α, lead to activation of Akt in several types of human cancer. (Vivanco and Sawyers,

child:  i | {}
Nature Reviews in Cancer | 
(2002) 2: 489-501.

parent:  p | {'num': 'p-0005'}

The tumor suppressor, PTEN, is a critical negative regulator of Akt activation by PI3-K. Myers et al.
```

or using `repr()` to show string literals instead:

```
parent:  p | {'num': 'p-0003'}
'\nProtein kinases are involved in the signal transduction pathways linking growth factors, hormones and other cell regulation molecules to cell growth, survival and metabolism under both normal and pathological conditions. One such protein kinase, protein kinase B (also known as Akt), is a serine/threonine kinase that plays a central role in promoting the proliferation and survival of a wide range of cell types, thereby protecting cells from apoptosis (programmed cell death) (Khwaja,\n'
child:  i | {}
'Nature' | u'\n33-34 (1990)). Three members of the Akt/PKB subfamily of second-messenger regulated serine/threonine protein kinases have been identified and are termed Akt1/PKB\u03b1, Akt2/PKB\u03b2, and Akt3/PKB\u03b3. A number of proteins involved in cell proliferation and survival have been described as substrates of Akt in cells. Two examples of such substrates include glycogen synthase kinase-3 (GSK3) and Forkhead transcription factors (FKs). See Brazil and Hemmings,\n'
child:  i | {}
'Trends in Biochemical Sciences' | '\n26, 675-664.\n'
parent:  p | {'num': 'p-0004'}
u'\nA number of protein kinases and phosphatases regulate the activity of Akt; For instance, activation of Akt is mediated by phosphatidylinositol 3-kinase (PI3-K), which initiates the binding of second messenger phospholipids to the pleckstrin homology (PH) binding domain of Akt. The binding anchors Akt to plasma membrane and results in phosphorylation and activation of the enzyme. Amplifications of the catalytic subunit of PI3-K, p110\u03b1, or mutations in the PI3-K regulatory subunit, p85\u03b1, lead to activation of Akt in several types of human cancer. (Vivanco and Sawyers,\n'
child:  i | {}
'Nature Reviews in Cancer' | '\n(2002) 2: 489-501.\n'
parent:  p | {'num': 'p-0005'}
'\nThe tumor suppressor, PTEN, is a critical negative regulator of Akt activation by PI3-K. Myers et al.\n'
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I did that too, but I tried both cases. But I am not able to get text within children/grandchildren tags and using the tail attribute.

Comment: Does that mean you modified my first line? Like, I said I want to get one tag of interest---this tag might not be the root and then do the extraction inside. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user89423: In my setup `root` is the `<description>` tag, because you gave us a more limited sample (I had to add in the tag even). Ignore that first line, that's why I stated it is simplified.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use itertext(), but if you want to step up your game a little bit you should try out [xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). It really shines in these types of situations.

Here's an example - the xpath I've given basically says:

Find all  tags anywhere in the XML document, and then return
the text for it and all children.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(open('t.xml').read())

for el in tree.xpath('//description/descendant-or-self::*/text()'):
    print el
```

Comment: `.xpath()` is a `lxml` extension, the OP seems to be using standard library ElementTree instead.

Comment: Right, I am using ElementTree.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem - elementtree supports xpath. http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: ElementTree supports a subset of XPath 1.0, not all of it.